# Powershell send result as html by email

Tags: powershell

I want to have the result of the following code sent by email as html. It is currently `write-host`. Looks like `ConvertTo-Html` wont work the way I expected...

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $SRCDIR1\*.xml | Select -ExpandProperty Name

$Result = Foreach ($item in $FileList)
{
    $DST |
        ForEach-Object {
            If (Test-Path -Path "$_\$item")
            {
                Write-Host "$item exist in $_" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            Else
            {
                Write-Host "$item does not exist in $_" -ForegroundColor Red  
            }
        }
}

$Result | ConvertTo-Html | out-file c:\temp\result.html
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: expecting if it can convert result of  `writh-host` to a html file....or if it can write to email body as html directly

Answer (score 1):

Not `ConvertTo-HTML` isn't working as expected, but your `$Result` doesn't have the expected content. In fact, it should be empty. `Write-Host` doesn't have an output, it only sends the text to the console. As you don't write anything else to your `$Result` variable, it's empty.

`ConvertTo-Html` requires a `PSObject` as input. But your input variable is empty, hence `ConvertTo-Htlm` can't convert anything.

An example would be something like

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Item = $item
    Exist = $true
}
```